# How do I obtain room seperators in revit 2017

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

I'm working an application which requires knowledge about which room border which other. In this situation it's relevant to know if a room border is a wall or a room seperator.

```
 public FindsRoomSeperators(){
        SpatialElementBoundaryOptions options = new SpatialElementBoundaryOptions();
        options.SpatialElementBoundaryLocation = SpatialElementBoundaryLocation.Finish;

        foreach (IList<Autodesk.Revit.DB.BoundarySegment> boundSegList in room.GetBoundarySegments(options))
                {
                    foreach (Autodesk.Revit.DB.BoundarySegment boundSeg in boundSegList)
                            if ((BuiltInCategory)el.Category.Id.IntegerValue == BuiltInCategory.OST_RoomSeparationLines)
                                 //proccess el
                 }
   }
```

However as the  of revit 2017 this code now throws the Method not found: 'Autodesk.Revit.DB.Element Autodesk.Revit.DB.BoundarySegment.get_Element()'. exception suggesting that this method has been removed.

```
      var geometry = (Solid)room.get_Geometry(new Options()).First();
      var faces = geometry.Faces;
```

And while this does allow me to judge stuff like whatever or not a floor is standing at an angle it does not tell me which of the edges come from walls and which from room sepeartors.

Ideally I would be able to take the faces we have and check to see if any of the edges of a face is a room seperator. I already have a list of all walls if that helps.

So how does one do this in revit 2017? Preferably without breaking compatability with 2015.

Comment: the GetBoundarySegments() was not removed from the API on 2017, it still there (not even marked as 'deprecated'). Aren't you missing a reference?

Comment: The code throws an exception in the foreach loop when called in 2017 but works fine in 2016 . The above method throws the exception: Method not found: 'Autodesk.Revit.DB.Element Autodesk.Revit.DB.BoundarySegment.get_Element()'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's expected and documented on the **Revit Platform API Changes and Additions** file ([see SDK](http://images.autodesk.com/adsk/files/REVIT_2017_SDK_(Update_June_23__2016).msi)), this method was marked as deprecated on 2016 and was removed on 2017.

Instead you should use **ElementId** or **LinkElementId** (see documentation).

```
foreach (Autodesk.Revit.DB.BoundarySegment boundSeg in boundSegList)
{
  Element el = doc.GetElement(boundSeg.ElementId); // or doc.GetElement(boundSeg.LinkElementId);
  if ((BuiltInCategory)el.Category.Id.IntegerValue == BuiltInCategory.OST_RoomSeparationLines)
  {

  }
}
```

Comment: Could it be that boundSeg.ElementId doesn' t exist in revit 2015? It gives me an error: Boundry segment does not contain a definition for 'ElementID'.

Comment: Yes the BoundarySegment.ElementId property was introduced on 2016 (as per documentation)

Comment: Do you happen to know a way to allow me to use both? I need to be competable with both 2015 and 2017.

Comment: you can use Dynamic, see my first suggestion (and improved version) at http://stackoverflow.com/a/33401274/4838205

Answer (score 2):

The **Revit Platform API Changes and Additions** documentation that Augusto points to above is also available online:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/04/whats-new-in-the-revit-2017-api.html

Simply search for BoundarySegment. The `get_Element` method that you are missing is actually a wrapper for the `Element` property, which was removed in Revit 2017.

A sample demonstrating the use of the .NET **Reflection** library to support different functionality in different versions of Revit is provided by The Building Coder at

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/07/multi-version-add-in.html